# openxlsx - Merge 2 cells on several rows in one call?

Tags: r, openxlsx

Is it currently possible to merge, say 2 cells (same row, consecutive columns), on several rows in one (or at least less than the total number of rows considered) call to `mergeCells`?

[EDIT]: Reproducible example:

```
library(openxlsx)

OutputFolder <- file.path(".", "Output")
if(!dir.exists(OutputFolder))   dir.create(OutputFolder)

OutputFile <- file.path(OutputFolder, "Reprex_Openxlsx_mergeCells.xlsx")

Workbook4Export <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb = Workbook4Export, sheetName = "Tab_1", zoom = 80, gridLines = FALSE)

for(i in 1:100000)
{
  mergeCells(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", cols = 1 + 0:1, rows = i)
}
```

Is there an alternative to this very long loop in terms of number of calls to `mergeCells`?
For instance with the natural GUI of Excel, one can copy the whole format of a row of 2 columns (here 2 merged columns on the first row) and then paste on the other 99 000 subsequent rows with just a click or two to have each and every of these rows with the 2 columns merged.

This is what I am ultimately looking for within `openxlsx`.

Comment: Have you checked `openxlsx` documentation: `?openxlsx::mergeCells` ? Please provide a reproducible example to make your problem explicit and allow solutions to be verified. Please also include the expected output. [MRE]

Comment: Of course I checked the documentation. I added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is anything "wrong" with the loop approach you put forward in the question.

It seems to be in the nature of things with `openxlsx` that on a one-to-one comparison there is a bit more typing to generate code compared with a one-off multiple click operation within  a workbook.

The benefit with `openxlsx` is that once the code is generated it is scalable: you can use it accurately n number of times without any more clicking. Even nicer if you are using the same approach multiple times to create you own function(s).

Anyway enough of that: here's an alternative using `purrr` (which just disguises the loop)

Might be interesting to benchmark the alternative approaches.

```
library(openxlsx)

OutputFolder <- file.path(".", "Output")
if(!dir.exists(OutputFolder))   dir.create(OutputFolder)

OutputFile <- file.path(OutputFolder, "Reprex_Openxlsx_mergeCells.xlsx")

Workbook4Export <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb = Workbook4Export, sheetName = "Tab_1", zoom = 80, gridLines = FALSE)

rows_2merge <- 1:100

purrr::walk(rows_2merge, ~mergeCells(wb = Workbook4Export, sheet = "Tab_1", cols = 1 + 0:1, rows = .x))

saveWorkbook(Workbook4Export, "Output/merge_cells_eg.xlsx")
```

Comment: It's not a matter of what is "wrong" or "true" (or "correct") but rather of speed.
Yes, in your solution the loop is implicit; I could also have used a `lapply` in my reproducible example. As `openxlsx` is programmed in C++, any internal loop would be much faster than an R loop. But it seems there is no internal loop alternative in the function `mergeCells`.